# CSS position:fixed - background-color disappear

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

This is the example : https://jsfiddle.net/5ahw3tec/

HTML

```css
html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}

    a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    body {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 0;
}

    .container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 1280px;
    padding: 0;
}

    #gnb {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
}

    #gnb .header-area img {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 80px;
}

    #gnb .header-area nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    left: 280px;
}

    #gnb .header-area ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

    #gnb .header-area li {
    margin-left: 80px;
}

    #gnb .header-area li a {
    color: #333333;
}

    #gnb .header-area li:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

    #gnb .header-area li a:hover {
    color: #18d28b;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="gnb">
    <div class="header-area">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="somelogo" alt="">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main>

</main>

<footer>

</footer>
 </div>
```

CSS

When I scroll down, the fixed menu bar(logo image and some lists) is located in the top of the page.

But, there is an issue. 
When I apply position:fixed to #gnb (in the example above), 
the background color(white) that I made earlier is disappeared. I don't know what the problem is exactly..

I want to keep the effect of background color too.

- I am applying Bootstrap for container class, but not for the menu bar.

Comment: i fixed this by addning `html{background: white;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below css for this:

see [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ahw3tec/1/)

CSS:

```
html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*   End global   */

body {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

#gnb {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#gnb .header-area img {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 80px;
}

#gnb .header-area nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    left: 280px;
}

#gnb .header-area ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

#gnb .header-area li {
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#gnb .header-area li a {
    color: #333333;
}

#gnb .header-area li:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#gnb .header-area li a:hover {
    color: #18d28b;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Why does the background color disappear?**

Well, you set the color to your container Element, and without any other specifications, the child elements inherit the white background (that's why you override it with pink!)

Setting your Header to `position: fixed` decouples the `#gnb` Element from his parent, so it does not have any background color, until you specify one and the color of the element below is visible (which is pink). So you have to manually set the color to white again.

So the answer of Jainam is correct, just add

`background-color: #fff` to your `#gnb`

Answer (score 0):

for fixed menu - use `margin-top` , `top: 0`

```css
html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 1280px;
    padding: 0;
}

/*new   */
header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#gnb {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 80px;    /* based on this height */
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;    /* new */
}

#gnb .header-area img {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 80px;
}

#gnb .header-area nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
    left: 280px;
}

#gnb .header-area ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

#gnb .header-area li {
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#gnb .header-area li a {
    color: #333333;
}

#gnb .header-area li:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#gnb .header-area li a:hover {
    color: #18d28b;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    margin-top: 80px;
    /* new  -  based on height given at #gnb */
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="gnb">
    <div class="header-area">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="somelogo" alt="">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  some text
</main>

<footer>

</footer>
 </div>
```